# dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.5

Tags: 12.04, apt, server, package-management, mysql

I upgrade my server from time to time with `apt-get update` then `apt-get upgrade` and don't use anything else. But now I have a problem with `mysql-server`. APT cannot upgrade anything else because of this. The error message says that it cannot configure it(?) When I try `dpkg --configure mysql-server`, it says my `mysql-server-core` is on 5.5.44 but it must to be on 5.5.43

How can I solve this?

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.5:
mysql-server-5.5 depends on mysql-server-core-5.5 (=  5.5.43-0ubuntu0.12.04.1); however:
Version of mysql-server-core-5.5 on system is 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.5
```

Using Ubuntu server 12.04-LTS

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way!

Because the `apt-get *` cannot do anything in my case, I removed `myql-server` and `mysql-server-core` with `dpkg` commands.

```
dpkg -r mysql-server-core-5.5
dpkg -r mysql-server-5.5
```

Now `mysql` is gone without altering other packages that depend on them!

Then I installed `mysql-server` again with `apt-get`

```
 sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

APT will install it like first time, but it will use your databases without any change and also root password is not changed!